# popups data scraping on given page range

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code to parse a popup info(emails), but I am unable to go on every page. It's only scraping one page. So how could I add range of pages on this code ?

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/?lang=en'

url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=org_list'

profile_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=profile&org_id='

num = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

with requests.session() as s:
    
    # load cookies:
    s.get(base_url)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    
    for tr in soup.select('tr[onclick]'):
        n = num.search(tr['onclick']).group(1)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(s.get(profile_url + n).content, 'html.parser')
        email = soup2.select_one('td:contains("E-Mail") + td')
        print(email.text)
```

This code was offered by Andrej Keseley and many thanks to him.

So what will be the addition to this code to scrape pages in given range?

Comment: What does the url look like for the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to load next pages:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/?lang=en'
url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=org_list'
profile_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=profile&org_id='
next_url = 'https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/controller.php?action=org_list&search_org_type=0&page=next&blacklisted=0'

num = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

with requests.session() as s:
    
    # load cookies:
    s.get(base_url)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    while True:

        if not soup.select('tr[onclick]'):
            break

        for tr in soup.select('tr[onclick]'):
            n = num.search(tr['onclick']).group(1)
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(s.get(profile_url + n).content, 'html.parser')
            email = soup2.select_one('td:contains("E-Mail") + td')
            print(email.text)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(next_url).content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, your code is working as always! ;) but after about 9000 emails i am getting an error, so how could I add any variable of ranges of pages ? for example I need from 9000 emails to 12000 emails (or same thing with pages ranges)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrej, your code is working as always! ;) but after about 9000 emails i am getting an error, so how could I add any variable of ranges of pages ? for example I need from 9000 emails to 12000 emails (or same thing with pages ranges)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000074893451D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tenders.procurement.gov.ge', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /public/library/controller.php?action=profile&org_id=67358 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000074893451D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Scrap/main.py", line 25, in 
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(s.get(profile_url + n).content, 'html.parser')
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 536, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 523, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tenders.procurement.gov.ge', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /public/library/controller.php?action=profile&org_id=67358 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000074893451D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))